# Does mysql configuration options accepts - instead of _?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

[Mysql 5.7 Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_instances) mentions that `innodb_buffer_pool_instances` can be set in `/etc/mysql/mysqld.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` as follows:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    = 16
```

However, an existing setup uses mysql configuration as follows (passed in `/etc/mysql/mysqld.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`):

```
[mysqld]
innodb-buffer-pool-instances    = 16
```

And it seems to be working.

Does mysql configuration options accept `-` instead of `_` in variables or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/command-line-options.html says:

> Within option names, dash (-) and underscore (_) may be used
>   interchangeably. For example, --skip-grant-tables and
>   --skip_grant_tables are equivalent. (However, the leading dashes cannot be given as underscores.)

This applies to options when you use them in option files, as well as command-line flags.

However, when using option variables in SQL queries, like in `SET GLOBAL read_only=ON`, you must use underscores only. Even putting the variable in back-ticks doesn't allow you to use hyphens.

```
mysql> set global `read_only`=ON;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> set global `read-only`=ON;
ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'read-only'

mysql> select @@`read_only`;
+---------------+
| @@`read_only` |
+---------------+
|             1 |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select @@`read-only`;
ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'read-only'
```